# Argument of type '(value: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to push a value to a state array but unable to as getting a TS error. I will put here the relevant components where the error can be seen. The error is on the child component, more specifically in the `handleValue(value => [...value, item.value])`.

Error:

```
Argument of type '(value: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]
```

Parent component:

```
const ChooseValuesScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [valuesProgress, setValuesProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const [convertPercentageIntoUnit, setUnit] = useState<number>(0)
  const [numberOfValuesSelected, setNumberOfValuesSelected] = useState<number>(0);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false,
        })
        setUnit(valuesProgress ? 1 : 0)
        setNumberOfValuesSelected(numberOfValuesSelected + convertPercentageIntoUnit)
    }, [navigation,valuesProgress, convertPercentageIntoUnit, value])  

    const renderItem: ListRenderItem<ItemProps> = ({item}) => <Item handleProgress{setValuesProgress} valuesProgress={valuesProgress} handleValue={setValue} data={item} />;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={[tw`bg-black h-full`,{}]}>
            <FlatList 
            data={values}
            keyExtractor={(item: ItemProps) => item.id}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            style={[tw``,{}]}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            numColumns={3}
            columnWrapperStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default ChooseValuesScreen;
```

Child component:

```
export type Props = {
    item: any,
    colorOnPress: string,
    pickedActiveOpacity: number,
    handleProgress: (valuesProgress : number) => void;
    valuesProgress: number,
    handleValue: (value : string[]) => void;
  };

const CustomButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ item ,pickedActiveOpacity, colorOnPress, handleProgress, valuesProgress, handleValue }) => {
    return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight 
                onPress={() => {
                    if(valuesProgress < 1){
                        handleProgress(valuesProgress+0.2)
                        handleValue(value => [...value, item.value])
                    }}}>
                    <Text style={[tw`text-black text-right m-auto`,{fontFamily:'Poppins'}]}>{item.value}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
    )
}
export default CustomButton;
```

If I were to pass a value only `handleValue(item.value)`, no error is seen and the state array will receive the value but what I want is for the values to remain in the array and not have a value replace the other.
Any ideas?

Comment: You've carefully typed `handleValue` as a function receiving an array, narrowing it from the actual type of a state setter, then called it with a _function_.

Answer (score 0):

In your props you declared `handleValue: (value : string[]) => void;` that means your function take one argument `value` as array of strings

In here `handleValue(value => [...value, item.value])` you pass a function as agrument instead of `string[]`

UPD.

```
type CustomFunction = (value: string) => string[]
...
// In your Props
handleValue: (CustomFunction) => void
```

Comment: thanks! so how can I declare the value as being a function in my props?

Comment: Check upd above or [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYDE4DsDGwCWyWUAvFABQBuAhgDZwQBcUSATvlgOYCUpAfC2DsuAbQC6AbgBQU0JCgALalgAmtCADU6DUhQBmWZvCRpMuAkV4kBlZPhXSpOIkigHmS1eq31oZPdh4hMRU2kwUlMxsHDz8gsKc4rwA3gC+EkA). Try to avoid `any` in your code cause you lose power of typescript and it's bring to your code more mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving it by changing the function type declaration to:
`handleValue((value:any) => [...value, item.value])`in the child component and props being `handleValue: (value:any) => void;`

I am sure there is a better way to do this so if anyone has a better solution let me know